# Libharu pdf creation : How to know the size of the printed text

Tags: c++, libharu

I'm currently using the [libharu](https://github.com/libharu/libharu) library in order to render some pdf in a C++ program.

I have no idea whether it is possible or not to know the size needed in order to draw a specific text with a specific font.

The [HPDF_Page_TextRect](https://github.com/libharu/libharu/wiki/API%3A-Graphics#HPDF_Page_TextRect) drawing method will return an `HPDF_PAGE_INSUFFICIENT_SPACE` message if the text can't fit in the rect provided, but I'd like to know if there is a way to calculate the minimum size in which a text will fit with a specific font.

In advace, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a workaround which consists in drawing the text outside the page while shrinking the rect width until the drawing fails. It's not subtil at all, but it works.

```
HPDF_STATUS drawString_2(HPDF_Page pdfPage, CString texte, COLORREF textColor, HPDF_Font font, HPDF_REAL fontSize, HPDF_REAL left, HPDF_REAL right, HPDF_REAL top, 
                         HPDF_REAL bottom, HPDF_TextAlignment alignment, HPDF_REAL textRise = 0, HPDF_TextRenderingMode renderingMode = HPDF_FILL);


HPDF_REAL calculateMaxWidthForTextInRect2(HPDF_Page pdfPage, CString texte, HPDF_REAL left, HPDF_REAL right, HPDF_REAL top, HPDF_REAL bottom, HPDF_Font font, HPDF_REAL fontSize);


HPDF_STATUS drawString_2(HPDF_Page pdfPage, CString texte, COLORREF textColor, HPDF_Font font, HPDF_REAL fontSize, HPDF_REAL left, HPDF_REAL right, HPDF_REAL top, 
                         HPDF_REAL bottom, HPDF_TextAlignment alignment, HPDF_REAL textRise, HPDF_TextRenderingMode renderingMode)
{
#ifdef DEBUG
        assert(font != NULL);
#else
        if (font == NULL)
            return 1;
#endif
    HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize(pdfPage, font, fontSize);
    HPDF_Page_SetTextRise(pdfPage, textRise);
    HPDF_Page_SetTextRenderingMode(pdfPage, renderingMode);
    HPDF_Page_SetRGBFill(pdfPage, GetRValue(textColor) / 255.f, GetGValue(textColor) / 255.f, GetBValue(textColor) / 255.f);
    HPDF_Page_BeginText(pdfPage);
    HPDF_STATUS returnValue = HPDF_Page_TextRect(pdfPage, left, top, right, bottom, (LPCSTR)texte, alignment, NULL);
    HPDF_Page_EndText(pdfPage);

    return returnValue;
}

HPDF_REAL calculateMaxWidthForTextInRect2(HPDF_Page pdfPage, CString texte, HPDF_REAL left, HPDF_REAL right, HPDF_REAL top, HPDF_REAL bottom, HPDF_Font font, HPDF_REAL fontSize)
{
    // Let's draw outside the page size, so the text, even invisible, will not be selectionnable and copyable
    HPDF_REAL leftTmp           = -(right - left);
    HPDF_REAL rightTmp          = 0;
    HPDF_REAL topTmp            = -(bottom - top);
    HPDF_REAL bottomTmp         = 0;

    HPDF_Page_SetTextRenderingMode(pdfPage, HPDF_INVISIBLE);

    // Let's reduce horizontally the rect until the drawing fails
    while (drawString_2(pdfPage, texte, RGB(0, 0, 0), font, fontSize, leftTmp, rightTmp, topTmp, bottomTmp, HPDF_TALIGN_CENTER, 0, HPDF_INVISIBLE) == HPDF_OK)
    {
        leftTmp ++;
        rightTmp --;
    }   

    // If no drawing has be performed, the text cannot be rendered in the provided rect
    if (rightTmp == 0)
        return -1;

    // Let's decrement the shifting in order to get the latest correct value
    leftTmp --;
    rightTmp ++;

    return (rightTmp - leftTmp);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way is to use HPDF_Page_TextWidth function to get the width of the text in current fontsize, character spacing and word spacing:

```
HPDF_STATUS FitText( 
                    HPDF_Page pdfPage, 
                    HPDF_Font pdfFont, 
                    HPDF_REAL pdfFontSize, 
                    HPDF_REAL rectProvidedLeft, 
                    HPDF_REAL rectProvidedRight, 
                    HPDF_REAL rectProvidedTop, 
                    char *pText )
{
    if ( pdfPage <= 0 || pdfFont <= 0 || pdfFontSize <= 0 )
        return HPDF_INVALID_PARAMETER;

    HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize ( pdfPage, pdfFont, pdfFontSize );
    HPDF_REAL dTextExtent = HPDF_Page_TextWidth ( pdfPage, pText );

    // reduce font size until text fit in provided rectangle
    HPDF_REAL nReducedFontSize = pdfFontSize;
    while ( dTextExtent > (rectProvidedRight-rectProvidedLeft) && nReducedFontSize >= 0 )
    {
        HPDF_Page_SetFontAndSize ( pdfPage, pdfFont, --nReducedFontSize );
        dTextExtent         = HPDF_Page_TextWidth ( pdfPage, pText );
    }
    if ( nReducedFontSize == 0 )
        return HPDF_STRING_OUT_OF_RANGE;

    HPDF_Page_BeginText     ( pdfPage );
    HPDF_Page_MoveTextPos   ( pdfPage, rectProvidedLeft, rectProvidedTop );
    HPDF_STATUS pdfStatus   = HPDF_Page_ShowText    ( pdfPage, pText );
    HPDF_Page_EndText       ( pdfPage );

    return pdfStatus;
}
```